# How to write a function that compares an enum with an enum case in Swift

Tags: swift, enums

Would it be possible in Swift to write a function that takes an enum and an enum case and compare them?

Below is the example use case, how would you write `isSameAction` function?

```
protocol Action {}


enum CounterAction: Action {
    case IncrementBy(Int)
    case DecrementBy(Int)
}

enum LoadingAction: Action {
    case Loading, Loaded
}


let action1 = CounterAction.IncrementBy(1)
let action2 = CounterAction.DecrementBy(2)
let action3 = LoadingAction.Loaded

let actions:  [Action] = [action1, action2, action3]

actions.filter(action in isSameAction(action, CounterAction.IncrementBy))
```

Comment: Could you give more context on what exactly you're trying to achieve? Consider the `Action` protocol, what exactly is it supposed to do? Sure it lets you put instances of both `CounterAction` and `LoadingAction` into the same array, but you can't actually do much with that. It has no requirements of its conforming types, so similar to `Any`, the only thing you can really do with objects that conform to that protocol is to cast them to their concrete type, and use them like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `if case` to check if your enumeration is `CounterAction.IncrementBy` and `return true` otherwise `return false`:

```
let filtered = actions.filter {
    if case CounterAction.IncrementBy = $0 { return true }
    return false
}
```